# Syntax of IF statement on SQL count

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In PowerShell I'm attempting to write an `if` statement on whether a `COUNT` result from SQL Server is greater than 0.  Below is what I have:

```bsh
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Our Connection String"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Source WHERE SourceId IS NULL"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$SqlAdapter.Fill($Table) | Out-Null

if ($Table > 0) {
    Write-Output "The Count is greater than zero, please investigate"
}
```

I know the `if` statement at the bottom is bad syntax, and I've tried many other ways of expressing it to no avail. I run the script, I don't get any errors, but it just completes and nothing happens. I have verified that if I remove the `Out-Null` from the `$SqlAdapter.Fill()` line, PowerShell will return a count number, so I know everything up until that point is working.

I just need to get it to write output if the count is greater than 1, which in this SQL query, it definitely is.  How would I write this `if` statement?

Comment: `$Table.What?? -gt 0`; also, it'll be simpler to just return a Scalar ([SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2)) vs a DataTable. (The first *column/row* data-slot contains the COUNT value.)

Comment: @user2864740 ok, but what goes in "What??" if it's just a COUNT query and the column has no name?

Comment: Well, .. let's see the ["what's that are are available"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2). Note that the first column/row will have the value of the COUNT. DataTables are better when dealing with "tables".

Comment: See [DataTable.Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Rows).Count for a "count of the rows" in the DataTable. However, it will still be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @user2864740 let me try your ExecuteScalar suggestion and see what I come up with.

Comment: @user2864740 I am successfully getting a count number returned using SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar.  But I am still having trouble determining how to wrap that count in an IF statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
if ($Table.Column1 -gt 0) {
    Write-Output "The Count is greater than zero, please investigate"
}
```

Since you are not providing any schema for your data table, the count will go into column name **Column1**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply capture the output of `$SqlAdapter.Fill($Table)` in a variable instead of suppressing it via `Out-Null` and then check that variable.

```
$cnt = $SqlAdapter.Fill($Table)

if ($cnt -gt 0) {
    # do stuff
}
```